# aws cdk IAM Account trust role gives 'Condition must be prefaced by a vendor" error

Tags: aws-cdk

I am trying to create this role using AWS CDK v2 and get an error:

```
'Conditions must be prefaced by a vendor. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 1c40e6e5-0dbf-41bc-a807-22a848955822; Proxy: null)'
```

What's wrong in the below code.?

```js
    // Create cdkTrustRole
    const role = new iam.Role(this, 'cdkTrustRole-AWSAccount-Role', {
      roleName: 'cdkTrustRole-AWSAccount-Role',
      description: 'cdkTrustRole role for Accessing billing,Usage and cost managment',
      assumedBy: new iam.PrincipalWithConditions(
        new iam.ArnPrincipal('arn:aws:iam::***********:root'),
        {
          StringEquals: {
            'sts.ExternalId': 'SJSDHJHSKJDHAShjfdsfsf'
          }
        }
      ),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyName(this, 'cdkTrustRoleROPolicy', 'cdkTrustRoleROPolicy'),
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyName(this, 'cdkTrustRoleBucketPolicy', 'cdkTrustRoleBucketPolicy'),
      ]
      
    });
```

Comment: Should be `sts:ExternalId` (`:` not `.`)

Comment: thanks @fedonev it worked . Another question on the same code as it failed to attach the two customer managed policy statements down the lines stating not exists. But worked when I changed them as inlinePolicies: { policy1, policy2}.  Is there any way we can create and add customer managed policies in the same iamRole stack itself. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sts:ExternalId` (`:` not `.`) will fix the error.

The `fromManagedPolicyName` method "imports" a reference to an existing Managed Policy.  To create a new one, instantiate a [ManagedPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.html) construct: `new iam.ManagedPolicy(this, ...)`

Comment: I have a policy document  defined as const myPolicy = new iam PolicyDocument({ statements...});    But when I use managedPolicies: [ new iam.ManagedPolicy(this, 'myPolicy', myPolicy)  it shows error in editor 'Argument of type 'PolicyDocument' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ManagedPolicyProps'.
  Property 'statements' is private in type 'PolicyDocument' but not in type 'ManagedPolicyProps'.ts(2345)'

Comment: see the full code and another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862613

Comment: @jvG Construct props are generally object types: `{ document: myPolicy }`.

Comment: Thank you @fedonev, now it creates customer managed policies.!