# AWS CDK generated CloudFormation stack doesn't show custom stack name and description

Tags: aws-cdk

I am using the following code which generate two CloudFormation template because of the instantiation of the cdk stack at the end(did that to have a custom name and description).

Is there any way we can avoid the instantiation just for giving Cloudfromation stack properties and thereby avoid second templates creation?

```js
    import { App, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import { Construct } from 'constructs';
    import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'; 
    
    export class IamStack extends Stack {
      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
    
        // create My RO policy
        const roPolicy = new iam.PolicyDocument({
          statements: [
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
              effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
              resources: [
                "*"
              ],
              actions: [
                "s3:List*",
                "sns:Get*",
                "sns:List*",
               ]
            })
          ]
          
        });
        //My bucket policy
        const bucketPolicy = new iam.PolicyDocument({
          statements: [
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
              effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
              resources: [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mycostusage/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mycostusage"
            ],
              actions: [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
              ]
            })
          ]
        });
        // Create MyRole
        const role = new iam.Role(this, 'My-AWSAccount-Role', {
          roleName: 'My-Role',
          description: 'My role for automation',
          assumedBy: new iam.PrincipalWithConditions(
            new iam.ArnPrincipal('arn:aws:iam::*********:root'),
            {
              StringEquals: {
                'sts:ExternalId': 'HJGSHJGAKJAHLLKLKK'
              }
            }
          ),
managedPolicies: [        
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSSavingsPlansReadOnlyAccess'),
        new iam.ManagedPolicy(this, 'myRoPolicy', { document: roPolicy }),
        new iam.ManagedPolicy(this, 'myBucketPolicy ', { document: bucketPolicy })
      ]
         });
       
      }
    }
    const app = new App();
    new IamStack(app, 'My-IAM-Role-Stack', {
      stackName: 'My-IAM-Role-Stack',
      description : 'IAM Roles for automation project ',
    });
```

EDIT: add My App.ts(from/bin folder)

```js
    import 'source-map-support/register';
    import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import { IamStack } from '../lib/iam-stack';
    
    const app = new cdk.App();
    new IamStack(app, 'IamStack', {
      /* If you don't specify 'env', this stack will be environment-agnostic.
       * Account/Region-dependent features and context lookups will not work,
       * but a single synthesized template can be deployed anywhere. */
    
      /* Uncomment the next line to specialize this stack for the AWS Account
       * and Region that are implied by the current CLI configuration. */
      // env: { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION },
    
      /* Uncomment the next line if you know exactly what Account and Region you
       * want to deploy the stack to. */
      // env: { account: '123456789012', region: 'us-east-1' },
    
      /* For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html */
    });
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your problem. Are you saying that this code produces 2 stacks?  What is the output of `cdk list` (use the same args as with synth/deploy)?

Comment: It create only one cdk stack but create two cloudFormation templates in the cdk.out folder and still the CloudFormation stack get deployed on to my aws account with default cdk stack name with no description. In order to have a custom stack name and description on my AWS CloudFormation stack I have added the instantiation  at the end of the code but now I have to manually deploy the second generated template to get those cloudformation stack name and description into my accounts.

Comment: Same applies to the Customer managed policies name , they are getting created with name 'cdkStackName-PolicyNameA/N-A/N' (random alpha numeric chars present in the name). something missing in the code to have meaningful names  for these generated cfn stacks, policies and roles ?

Comment: What's in your `app.ts` file? Please edit your question and add this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 2 apps, one in `app.ts` and another in `iam-stack.ts`.  Remove the app and stack instantiation code from `iam-stack.ts`, leaving only the class definition.  Instantiate the app and stack once, in `app.ts`.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev !, CloudFromation stack names are getting generated according to the app.ts file now.  Any idea how I can get the managed polices name without the cdk stack name prefixed and plha numeric chars at the end. ?

Comment: The [managedPolicyName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.html#managedpolicyname) prop does that.  However, using the default generated resource names is considered [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names).

Comment: Can I use the same cdk-stack for creating other CloudFormation stacks for IAM users/roles/policies rather than creating multiple stack,ts files ? what is the best practice ? Should I create multiple stack.ts files(eg., iam-user-stack.ts, iam-roles-stack.ts, iam-policy-stack.ts  etc) and  use the single app.ts by commenting-out the unwanted stacks ? Also, is there any way we can generate CloudFormation Stackset directly from cdk ?

Comment: @jvG The CDK [best practices doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-separate) says: _There is no hard and fast rule to how many stacks your application needs. You'll usually end up basing the decision on your deployment patterns._